# Eventual consistency in RDBMS (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, cassandra, database-replication

I understand RDBMS databases like Oracle are not really meant for eventual consistency. But is it technically not feasible to customize oracle to follow eventual consistency model (say like what cassandra is supporting?)

For example: Cant we have two Oracle clusters (with it's own storage) connected by an active data-guard replicating in both directions? i.e., Active-Active! I have seen Active-Passive model in many production systems. But Is Active-Active feasible in Oracle?

Comment: One of the main features of RDBMS's is consistency, why would you want to relax that condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* build it using GoldenGate, but consider using Oracle Sharding, available in 18c.  That way, you can just declare the replication topology you want using the `GDSCTL` command syntax and Oracle will make it happen (using GoldenGate).

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/shard/sharding-overview.html#GUID-0F39B1FB-DCF9-4C8A-A2EA-88705B90C5BF

In particular, check out section 7.1 about High Availability and integration with Oracle GoldenGate.

#### Response about Active-Active

I cannot say for sure, but Oracle's documentation strongly implies it can be used in an active-active arrangement.  From Oracle's documentation:

> 7.1.1 When To Choose Oracle GoldenGate for Shard High Availability When should Oracle GoldenGate be employed as your high availablility
>   solution for Oracle Sharding?
>
> Oracle GoldenGate should be your preferred high availability solution
>   in the following cases:
>
> **All shards read-write**. With Active Data Guard the DR/backup shards are
>   read-only.
>
> More flexibility in deploying shards. Each shard can be on a different
>   operating system or a different database version.
>
> More than a single updatable copy of the data. For example, with
>   Oracle GoldenGate, using the replication factor of 4, **you can have 4
>   read-write copies of the data that can be updated**.

Comment: This is not an active-active solution. This is a multiple active-passive approach with active node for each part of the data and multiple passive copies.

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński I've updated my answer with what  led me to believe that it _is_ an active-active solution.  If you have experience or something clearer from Oracle on the subject, please share it and I will update or withdraw my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: So actually, if you want to use Active - Active you have to use Oracle GoldenGate. Sharding is just an additional layer to collect to present the data in one source.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an active-active bidirectional **asynchronous** replication using Oracle GoldenGate or any other replication engine. But you have to strictly define the way that the rows are handled.

For example:

1. If the same row is updated at the same time in both sites - which one should be more important?
2. If you are assigning new identifiers to rows (like sequence) you have to make sure that you won't be assigning the same identifier at the both sites.

Or you can create a **synchronous** replication using Oracle RAC. You would create one big database that is created on 2 hosts with a shared storage. Every change made at one site is immediately visible on the other.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! When you say synchronous replication between 2 hosts with a shared storage: do you mean, a) 2 hosts will be using same disk but each will have it's own copy of data? or b) 2 hosts will be using same disk but using just one copy of data? To me: the word "replication" and "shared storage" are conflicting. one of the purpose of the replication is to have an additional copy of data isn't?

Comment: Actually using Oracle RAC as a substitute for Active-Active replication is a bit strained. Actually you would be using one database here. For true replication you need an additional tool like GoldenGate.